# Connect EC2 and RDS using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

When I try to connect Amazon EC2 instance with RDS instance using codeigniter on EC2, I get a message: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. But when using a classic dedicated server with same parameters to connect to RDS, connection is successful.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxxxxxx'; 
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxxxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = 3306;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['ssl_set'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['ssl_key'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cert'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_ca'] = realpath('./mycertificate.pem');
$db['default']['ssl_capath'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cipher'] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to access your RDS from another server I would say your Security Groups may be stopping access between your EC2 and RDS. Are they inside separate private subnets in a VPC?

If so you should assign inside the security groups the ability for each instance to access and communicate with each other on port 3306 (you can actually assign a Security Group as a source in the Security Group tabs which is awesome!)

If not, what does your environment look like between the EC2 and the RDS?

Comment: Hi Zac. Thank you very much for this answer! Security Group for EC2 and RDS instances is the same: quicklaunch-1. Also, VPC for RDS and EC2 is the same. Subnet for EC2 instance is included in array of RDS subnets. Port 3306 (tcp) for Security Group quicklaunch-1 is opened.